# Getting first day of week from week number in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection containing date field. I'm Grouping records by week and other related fields.

This is my aggregation query:

```js
db.raw.aggregate([
    { "$match" : {
        "Timestamp":{
            "$gte": new Date("2012-05-30"), 
            "$lt": new Date("2014-07-31")
        }
    }},
    { "$group" : {
        "_id":{ 
            "ApplicationId": "$ApplicationId",
            "Country": "$Country",
            "week":{ "$week": "$Timestamp" }
        },
        "Date":{ "$first": "$Timestamp" },
        "Visits": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

I want to Project :  Visits and Start Date of week from week number.

Comment: do you want retrieve only Visits and Week ?

Comment: I want to retrieve Visit and first Day of that week.
e.g
{ "Visit":40 ,"SummaryDate":"27/07/2014" ,"week":30 }

Summary Date is start date of the week no 30

Comment: Maybe you have to Do another `$group` By `$week` and get `$first`... Can I see a document for Replicate your Database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want a "date value" representing the date at the start of the week. Your best approach is "date math" with a little help from the aggregation operator [**`$dayOfWeek`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/):

```js
db.raw.aggregate([
  { "$match" : {
    "Timestamp":{
      "$gte": new Date("2012-05-30"), 
      "$lt": new Date("2014-07-31")
    }
  }},
  { "$group" : {
    "_id":{ 
      "ApplicationId": "$ApplicationId",
      "Country": "$Country",
      "weekStart":{ 
        "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$subtract": [ "$Timestamp", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
            { "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] },
              0,
              { "$multiply": [
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                { "$subtract": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] }
              ]}
            ]}
          ]},
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": [
              { "$subtract": [ "$Timestamp", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
              { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] },
                0,
                { "$multiply": [
                  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                  { "$subtract": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] }
                ]}
              ]}
            ]},
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]}
        ]
      }
    },
    "Date":{ "$first": "$Timestamp" },
    "Visits": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Or a little cleaner with [**`$let`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) from MongoDB 2.6 and upwards:

```js
db.raw.aggregate([
  { "$match" : {
    "Timestamp":{
      "$gte": new Date("2012-05-30"), 
      "$lt": new Date("2014-07-31")
    }
  }},
  { "$group" : {
    "_id":{ 
      "ApplicationId": "$ApplicationId",
      "Country": "$Country",
      "weekStart":{ 
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "dayMillis": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            "beginWeek": {
              "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$Timestamp", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] },
                  0,
                  { "$multiply": [
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                    { "$subtract": [{ "$dayOfWeek": "$Timestamp" }, 1 ] }
                  ]}
                ]} 
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$subtract": [
              "$$beginWeek",
              { "$mod": [ "$$beginWeek", "$$dayMillis" ]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Date":{ "$first": "$Timestamp" },
    "Visits": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

The resulting value in the "grouping" is the epoch milliseconds that represents the start of the day at the start of the week. The "start of the week" is generally considered to be "Sunday", so if you intend another day then you would need to adjust by the appropriate amount. The [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator with the `$dayMillis` variable value can be used here to apply "Monday" for example.

It's not a date object, but something that you can easily feed to another method to construct a date object in post processing.

Also note that other things you are using such as [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) usually require that the documents are sorted in a particular order, or generally by your "Timestamp" values. If those documents are not already ordered then you either [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) first or use an operator such as [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) to get the first actual timestamp in the range.

Answer (score 7):

For mongo >= v3.4, look at weekStart.
The idea is to substruct milliseconds from given Timestamp

```
db.raw.aggregate([
         // stage 1
        { "$match" : {
            "Timestamp":{
                "$gte": ISODate("2012-05-30"), 
                "$lt": ISODate("2014-07-31")
            }
        }},

         // stage 2
        { "$project" : {

           ApplicationId: 1,
           Country: 1,
           week: {$isoWeek: "$Timestamp"},

           // [TRICK IS HERE] Timestamp - dayOfWeek * msInOneDay
           weekStart: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: { // convert date
             $subtract: ["$Timestamp", {$multiply: [ {$subtract:[{$isoDayOfWeek: "$Timestamp"},1]}, 86400000]}] 
           }}},

         // stage 3
        { "$group" : {
        "_id":{ 
            "ApplicationId": "$ApplicationId",
            "Country": "$Country",
            "week": "$week"
        },
        "Date":{ "$first": "$weekStart" },
        "Visits": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}        
 ])
```

Answer (score 3):

With MongoDB 3.6

```
{ 
  '$project' : {
    'firstDateOfWeek': {
        '$dateFromString': {
            'dateString': {
                '$concat': [
                    {
                        '$toString': '$_id.year'
                    }, 
                    '-', 
                    {
                        '$toString': '$_id.week'
                    }
                ]
             },
             'format': "%G-%V"
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From mongo 3.6
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/

```
db.raw.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "Timestamp": {
                "$gte": new Date("2012-05-30"),
                "$lt": new Date("2014-07-31")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "ApplicationId": "$ApplicationId",
                "Country": "$Country",
                "week": {
                    "$isoWeek": "$Timestamp"
                },
                                "year": {
                                    "$year": "$Timestamp"
                                }
            },
            "Visits": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "Date": {
                $dateFromParts: {
                    isoWeekYear: '$_id.year',
                    isoWeek: '$_id.week',
                    isoDayOfWeek: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB >= v5.0 there is an even easier option now with the [$dateTrunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateTrunc) operator, e.g.

```
$project: {
  weekStart: {
    $dateTrunc: {
      date: "$Timestamp",
      unit: "week",
      startOfWeek: "Monday",
    }
  },
}
```